# c# HttpClient with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient

I execute a lot of request to some the resources with `HttpClient`. 
To avoid licks I use it as single instance. Something like that... 
I want to use proxy, so how I can use different proxies for each request?

Thanks!

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var result = Client.GetAsync("http://aspnetmonsters.com").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Connections done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: create and auth a HttClient for every proxy you have. Then use the instance matching your request-address

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I misread the question. 
It's not about how to use a random IWebProxy with HttpClientHandler, but how to work around being unable to reset the proxy property of the same HttpClientHandler once the first request has started.

The problem is that you can't reset the proxy of the HttpClientHandler...

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'This instance has already started
> one or more requests. 
> Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.'

But it's still rather easy.

- Proxy property of HttpClientHandler takes an object that implements IWebProxy.
- IWebProxy interface has a method GetProxy that return the Uri of the proxy.
- So you can make your own class that implements this interface and control how it returns the Uri of the proxy with GetProxy.
- You can make it wrap another IWebProxy, and in GetProxy it would return GetProxy of the inner IWebProxy.
- This way, you won't have to change the Proxy property of the HttpClientHandler, you can just change the inner IWebProxy.

Implementation:

```
public class WebProxyService
  : System.Net.IWebProxy
{
    protected System.Net.IWebProxy m_proxy;


    public System.Net.IWebProxy Proxy
    {
        get { return this.m_proxy ??= System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; }
        set { this.m_proxy = value; }
    }

    System.Net.ICredentials System.Net.IWebProxy.Credentials
    {
        get { return this.Proxy.Credentials; }
        set { this.Proxy.Credentials = value; }
    }


    public WebProxyService()
    { } // Constructor 

    public WebProxyService(System.Net.IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        this.Proxy = proxy;
    } // Constructor 


    System.Uri System.Net.IWebProxy.GetProxy(System.Uri destination)
    {
        return this.Proxy.GetProxy(destination);
    }

    bool System.Net.IWebProxy.IsBypassed(System.Uri host)
    {
        return this.Proxy.IsBypassed(host);
    }


}
```

And then usage goes like this:

```
public class AlternatingProxy 
{


    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Test()
    {
        string url = "http://aspnetmonsters.com";
       
        System.Net.WebProxy[] proxies = new[] {
            null,
            new System.Net.WebProxy("104.238.172.20", 8080),
            new System.Net.WebProxy("104.238.167.193", 8080),
            new System.Net.WebProxy("136.244.102.38", 8080),
            new System.Net.WebProxy("95.179.202.40", 8080)
        };

        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        WebProxyService proxyService = new WebProxyService();
        
        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient hc = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(
          new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler { UseProxy = true, Proxy = proxyService }
          ))
        {
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148");
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "fr-FR, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, it;q=0.7, *;q=0.5");
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.baidu.com");
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true; 

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                proxyService.Proxy = proxies[rnd.Next(proxies.Length)];
                string response = await hc.GetStringAsync(url);
            }
        }

    } // End Task Test  


} // End Class TestMe
```

---

### Edit:

If you want to use a singleton, maybe this is an idea:

public class WebProxyService
: System.Net.IWebProxy
{

```
    protected System.Net.IWebProxy m_proxy;


    public System.Net.IWebProxy Proxy
    {
        get { return this.m_proxy ??= System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; }
        set { this.m_proxy = value; }
    }

    System.Net.ICredentials System.Net.IWebProxy.Credentials
    {
        get { return this.Proxy.Credentials; }
        set { this.Proxy.Credentials = value; }
    }


    public WebProxyService()
    { } // Constructor 


    public WebProxyService(System.Net.IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        this.Proxy = proxy;
    } // Constructor 


    protected System.Func<System.Net.WebProxy>[] proxies = new System.Func<System.Net.WebProxy>[] {
            delegate(){ return new System.Net.WebProxy("104.238.172.20", 8080); },
            delegate (){ return new System.Net.WebProxy("104.238.167.193", 8080);},
            delegate(){ return new System.Net.WebProxy("136.244.102.38", 8080);},
            delegate(){ return new System.Net.WebProxy("95.179.202.40", 8080);}
        };


    System.Uri System.Net.IWebProxy.GetProxy(System.Uri destination)
    {
        return proxies[RandomGen2.Next(proxies.Length)]().GetProxy(destination);
    }


    bool System.Net.IWebProxy.IsBypassed(System.Uri host)
    {
        return this.Proxy.IsBypassed(host);
    }



    private static class RandomGen2
    {
        private static System.Random _global = new System.Random();

        [System.ThreadStatic]
        private static System.Random _local;

        public static int Next(int maxValue)
        {
            System.Random inst = _local;
            if (inst == null)
            {
                int seed;
                lock (_global) seed = _global.Next();
                _local = inst = new System.Random(seed);
            }
            return inst.Next(maxValue);
        }
    }


} // End Class WebProxyService
```

---

### Edit 2:

It's still not thread-safe if you change the proxy. 
Therefore, using a fixed immutable proxy-list and blocking the set-property.
This way, it should be thread-safe.

```
public class WebProxyService
      : System.Net.IWebProxy
{


    protected System.Net.IWebProxy[] m_proxyList;

    public System.Net.IWebProxy Proxy
    {
        get
        {
            // https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/getting-random-numbers-in-a-thread-safe-way/
            if (this.m_proxyList != null)
                return this.m_proxyList[ThreadSafeRandom.Next(this.m_proxyList.Length)];
            
            return System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("It is not thread-safe to change the proxy-list.");
        }
    }

    System.Net.ICredentials System.Net.IWebProxy.Credentials
    {
        get { return this.Proxy.Credentials; }
        set { this.Proxy.Credentials = value; }
    }


    public WebProxyService()
    {
    } // Constructor 


    public WebProxyService(System.Net.IWebProxy[] proxyList)
    {
        this.m_proxyList = proxyList;
    } // Constructor 


    System.Uri System.Net.IWebProxy.GetProxy(System.Uri destination)
    {
        return this.Proxy.GetProxy(destination);
    }


    bool System.Net.IWebProxy.IsBypassed(System.Uri host)
    {
        return this.Proxy.IsBypassed(host);
    }


} // End Class WebProxyService
```

---

Old answer:
----

Using a proxy with HttpClient in ASP.NET-Core is actually quite simple. 
All you need to do is set the handler in the HttpClient-constructor. 
Then set the proxy-property of the handler for each request. 
Like this:

```
public class Program
{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://aspnetmonsters.com";
        System.Net.WebProxy[] proxies = new[] {
            null,
            new System.Net.WebProxy("104.238.172.20", 8080),
            new System.Net.WebProxy("104.238.167.193", 8080),
            new System.Net.WebProxy("136.244.102.38", 8080),
            new System.Net.WebProxy("95.179.202.40", 8080)
        };

        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888"),
            UseProxy = true,
        })
        {

            using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient hc = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    handler.Proxy = proxies[rnd.Next(proxies.Length)];
                    await hc.GetAsync(url);

                    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent
                    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148");
                    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "fr-FR, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, it;q=0.7, *;q=0.5");
                    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.baidu.com");

                    using (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.GetAsync(url))
                    {
                        // using (var fs = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                        // { await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs); }
                        byte[] ba = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                    } // End Using response 

                } // Next i 

                System.Console.WriteLine("Ending connections");
            } // End Using hc 

        } // End Using handler 

        System.Console.WriteLine("--- Press any key to continue --- ");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    } // End Task Main 

} // End Class Program
```

Comment: Apologies for the downvote, Stefan, but I have a couple of concerns with this answer. Firstly it doesn't answer the question of how to use different proxies for separate requests using the same `HttpClient` instance. Secondly it shows pretty immediate disposal of HttpClient, which will lead to socket exhaustion.

Comment: @Josh Gallagher: You're right, I did not specify the part of re-setting the proxy of the handler in the old response. But it wouldn't have worked anyway. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. When you say it wouldn't have worked, you mean the old code or this new code? The new code looks like it would work, but it still has two problems. One is that the `HttpClient` instance is being disposed where it should be held for the lifetime of the process (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests). The other is that if you share that client across threads, you'd get race conditions on changing the proxy. I think the only way is multiple clients.

Comment: @Josh Gallagher: I wasn't thinking of using this in an ASP.NET context.  Naturally, then you need to create a HttpClient for each thread, or use locks, But locks would undermine the performance gains of using multiple threads. Whyever they don't close the underlying socket immediately. Perhaps, an easier fix for this is "hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true; ". That should close the connection immediately after each request. Just don't DI the service as singleton, use either Transient or Scoped, depending on needs. Also, there is rand, which would have to be attribute thread-static.

Comment: @Josh Gallagher: If you'd want this as singleton, maybe you can include the proxy list and the rand (with thread-static attribute) inside the WebProxyService and dynamically return a different proxy on every call to IWebProxy.GetProxy. Then it could be used as singleton, and you wouldn't have to dispose the client. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/getting-random-numbers-in-a-thread-safe-way/

Comment: @Josh Gallagher: Added a variant  of WebProxyService with thread-static random. See "Edit". What do you think ?  Of course, you would have to pass the proxies as arguments into the constructor. Then, you could just use the same HttpClient all over, assuming HttpClient itself is thread-safe. Somehow, this whole thing strikes my as very fishy. Also, I don't know if it's necessary to create a new webproxy inside GetProxy though, or if you could just use an array of new System.Net.WebProxy.

Comment: I think there's a germ of an idea here, as I suspect the use case is that there are specific proxies for specific URLs. Implementing IWebProxy with a switch statement would work, where the WebProxyService is stateless and already has references to all the real IWebProxy instances it will ever need. However, in your solution it is not thread safe to change the WebProxyService.Proxy, as thread 1 could set it to "A", then thread 2 sets it to "B", then thread 1 makes the HttpClient call expecting the proxy to be "A" whereas it is now "B".

Comment: @Josh Gallagher: True. Additionally, I don't know know if it internally calls set of the IWebProxy.Proxy property. If I change this to throw an exception on set, and just random the proxy on get, then it should work accross threads, though.  See Edit 2. Now if anything externally sets proxy, there will be an exception. Therefore, it should now be thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to implement IWebProxy.

here is a very row sample.

First implement IWebProxy

```
public class MyProxy : IWebProxy {
public MyProxy() {  credentials = new NetworkCredential( user, password ); }
private NetworkCredential credentials;
public ICredentials Credentials
{
    get = > credentials;
    set = > throw new NotImplementedException();
}
private Uri proxyUri;
public Uri GetProxy( Uri destination )
{
    return proxyUri; // your proxy Uri
}
public bool IsBypassed( Uri host )
{
    return false;
}
private const string user = "yourusername";
private const string password = "password";}
```

Then provide it to handler in HttpClient

```
public class MyHttpClient {
internal static HttpResult httpMethod( ... )
{
    var _client = client();
    try
    {
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage( method, url );
        message.Content = new StringContent( content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" );
        var result = _client.SendAsync( message ).Result;// handle result
    }
    catch( Exception e ){}
}
private static HttpClient client()
{
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = new MyProxy() };
    var httpClient = new MyClient( new Uri( "baseurl" ), httpClientHandler );
    return httpClient;
```

Answer (score -1):

So basically to be able to change proxies you will need a reference on the `HttpClientHandler`.
A simple example can be found here: [C# use proxy with HttpClient request](http://dineshvr.blogspot.gr/2016/03/c-use-proxy-with-httpclient-request.html)
and another one here: [Simple C# .NET 4.5 HTTPClient Request Using Basic Auth and Proxy](https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915)

I would suggest to keep the `HttpClientHandler` on a private field and use the reference to change the proxy everytime you need it.
Keep in mind though that if you need to use different proxies simultaneously you would need to have multiple instances of the `HttpClientHandler` class.

If you need me to make a sample code for that. Ping me.

Thank you.

Comment: But how can you set HttpClientHandler to instance of HttpClient after it was created?

Comment: @Sanja Melnichuk the HttpClientHandler needs to be set up only at construction. If you keep the reference you can make changes to it without the need to reconstruct the HttpClient

Comment: So I have one static httpclient and HttpCleintHandler, I use it in different threads, each thread use it's own proxy, how can I be sure that I change proxy for upcoming request?

Comment: @Sanja Melnichuk if you read more carefully on my original answer I say that if you want to use it simultaneously you will need to have more than one. Just to clarify the most expensive to create is the HttpClientHandler not the HttpClient.

Comment: This is incorrect advice. While you can change the proxy of the handler attached to httpclient before the first request has been sent, any subsequent attempt to change the proxy will result in an exception being thrown.

Comment: @cubesnyc have you actually tried the example and resulted in an exception. Also what is the exception thrown ?

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos did you read what I wrote? the example will work as long as a request has not been sent through the httpclient. after a request has been sent, trying to change the proxy property on the handler will result in an invalidoperation exception.

Comment: @cubesync first of all I don't appreciate your tone. Second I say in my answer that you may need multiple instances. For the exception I didn't experience it before so I will try to replicate and come back with a solution. Did you try to change the http client properties or the http client handler?